# Как отобразить созданный маршрут в api google maps на Гугл карты?

Tags: google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api

На сайте используется Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference со службой маршрутов.

Так вот, пользователь создает маршрут, после чего нужно создать ссылку, переходя по которой пользователь попадает на Гугл карты с уже проложенным маршрутом.

Как данный вопрос можно реализовать?

**Обновление**

Простите виноват, уточню задачу.

Один пользователь создает маршрут, а другой пользователь (а точнее менеджер) должен увидеть созданный маршрут у себя в заявке.

Т.к. заявка приходит посредством почты, то передать маршрут видится возможным через ссылку.
К примеру, вот сгенерированная ссылка:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Украинка, Киевская область, Украина/50.15009569999999,30.746957000000066/50.1877935,30.585807799999998/50.17840169999999,30.31590349999999/50.17263,30.51898879999999/Украинка, Киевская область, Украина
```

По этой ссылке в Гугл Картах можно увидеть проложенный маршрут от начальной до конечной точки через промежуточные. Но это не дает полной картины. К примеру, если пользователь перетянет маршрут, тогда менеджер, который смотрит заявку, не увидит измененного маршрута, а только тот, который отображен в ссылке.

Задача в следующем: как созданный маршрут в API картах переместить в web-сервис Гугл карты?

Comment: По этой ссылке в Гугл Картах можно увидеть проложенный маршрут от начальной до конечной точки через промежуточные. Но это не дает полной картины. К примеру если пользователь перетянет маршрут тогда менеджер который смотрит заявку не увидит измененного маршрута, а только тот который отображен в ссылке.

Задача в следующем: как созданный маршрут в API картах переместить в web-сервис Гугл карты?

Answer (score 1):

А если у вас уже подключен API карт, зачем отсылать пользователя на гугл карты? Сделайте карту у себя на сервере на отдельной странице и показывайте маршрут там.